# O que significa colocar o comando 'as' depois do comado de 'import' no código abaixo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

O 'as' está na função send_to_twitter(msg)

```
import urllib.request
import time

def send_to_twitter(msg):
    import twitter as t:
    CONSUMER_KEY = '1wrnsF5lB8fEWVzRdvlIqdTle'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'eTiylDUHLJgGnTCcxzzCtzHXG4OlHrbY6wLvuZUnAEhrokyNAF'
    ACCESS_KEY = '2325915097-q2JYaZ3UGeL9Pr95BJC7643NMyETY6x7Bb8T1q1'
    ACCESS_SECRET = '8GRq4e9ukVKcC8XjroM3iLKuZYOM2QtFEdCHXG3TXx0zo'
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    api.update_status(msg)
    print(msg)

def get_price():
    page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://beans-r-us.appspot.com/prices-loyalty.html")
    text = page.read().decode("utf8")
    where = text.find('>$')
    start_of_price = where + 2
    end_of_price = start_of_price + 4
    return(text[start_of_price : end_of_price])

escolha = input("Precisa do valor imediatamente? ")

if escolha == 'y':
    send_to_twitter(get_price())
else:
    if escolha == 'n':
        price = 99.99
        while price > 4.74:
            price = float(get_price())
            time.sleep(3)
        send_to_twitter('BUY!')
    else:
        print("Voce nao escolheu nada")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

De acordo com [na documentação](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html)<sup>(en)</sup> o `as` em `import twitter as t:` no Python significa que você está criando um aliás para o módulo importado.

`import` **sem** a prática do aliás:

```
>>>import math
>>>math.pi
>>>3.141592653589793
etc..
```

`import` **com** a prática do aliás:

```
>>>import math as m
>>>m.pi
>>>3.141592653589793
etc..
```

Você pode ler mais em [Importing Modules](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/import.html)<sup>(en)</sup>.

Observação do Matheus Saraiva:

> A utilidade mais prática disso é que você pode dar nomes mais
>   significativos para uma classe ou função importada e usar o novo nome
>   no seu código no lugar do nome original. Eu também uso em casos onde o
>   nome de uma função importada é um pouco grande então crio a alias para
>   não ter que digitar aquela função com nome enorme toda vez que
>   precisar usá-la.

Comment: Complemento: A utilidade mais prática disso é que você pode dar nomes mais significativos para uma classe ou função importada e usar o novo nome no seu código no lugar do nome original.
Eu também uso em casos onde o nome de uma função importada é um pouco grande então crio a alias para não ter que digitar aquela função com nome enorme toda vez que precisar usá-la.

Answer (score 6):

Como @AckLay explicou, você pode usar a palavra *as* como um apelido para o módulo importado no Python.

Essa sintaxe foi proposta pela [PEP 221](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/) e como explicado nesse documento, não tinha a intenção de ser uma palavra-chave do Python, mas consta da lista de palavras-chave dessa linguagem.

**Imprime a lista de palavras-chave no Python 2.7.*:**

```html
>>> import keyword
>>> print(keyword.kwlist)
```

> as is used to create an alias while importing a module. It means
>   giving a different name (user-defined) to a module while importing it.

Fonte: [Programiz - List Of Keywords In Python Programming](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keyword-list#as)

Answer (score 0):

Ele significa "como"

```
import os as so
```

nesse caso você esta falando "Importe o módulo os e mude seu nome para esse código como so"

assim tu pode chamar os métodos dele pelo nome que você deu ao módulo:

```
os.chdir()
```

ele é útil para dar os nomes que deseja e também para diminuir o nome de alguns módulos que podem ser muito grandes para ficar escrevendo toda hora, por exemplo podemos ter um módulo com o nome meuModuloPython, esse nome muito grande, então podemos chamar ele de mp (modulo python) usado o as.

```
import meuModuloPython as mp
mp.fazalgo()
```